# $ G=H_1\times ... \times H_k $ and $ K \unlhd G.$ Then If $K$ is not contained in $Z(G)$, there exists $i$ such that $K\cap H_i \neq \{e\}$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let a group $G$ be a product of groups, i.e $ G=H_1\times ... \times H_k $ and $ K \unlhd G.$ Then If $K$ is not contained in $Z(G)$, there exists $i$ such that $K\cap H_i \neq \{e\}$.

It seems that I should use the fact that with $K$ being normal, $|KH|=\frac{|K||H_i|}{|K\cap H_i|}$. I tried it, but couldn't get any working proof out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose some $g = (h_1,\ldots,h_k) \in K \setminus Z(G)$. Then some $h_i \not\in Z(H_i)$ - let's assume $i=1$. So there exists $h \in H_1$ that does not centralize $h_1$. Now consider the commutator of $g$ with $(h,1,1,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: I actually ended up proving it by showing that any elements from two normal subgroups that intersect trivially must commute. Thus any $k \in K$ commutes with all elements of $H_i$ for every $i$, then K is central. Contradiction.

What result was I supposed to get from your hint? Sorry but I can't see it. I'm sure it's pretty similar because my proof that two subgroups commute uses the commutator (but one of two general elements).

Comment: The commutaor I referred to is an element of $K \cap H_1$, thereby proving it nontrivial.